# OrderByRaw() then orderBy() in Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

Is it possible to use the following **orderByRaw()**. This orderByRaw() is returning the products in the same order as the whereIn(). Right now it's only the results in the orderByRaw order and not the **orderBy()**.

Is it possibile to combine these:

```
$ids;
$placeholders = implode(',',array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
Product::whereIn('id', $ids)->orderByRaw("field(id,{$placeholders})" ,$ids)->orderBy('views', 'des')->orderBy('created_at', 'des')->get();
```

Edit:
This is the SQL I get when I do toSql(). Why isn't this working?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `products` 
WHERE  `id` IN ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
ORDER  BY Field(id, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), 
          `views` DESC, 
          `created_at` DESC
```

Comment: I suppose you want to write 'desc' and not 'des'. This may be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s imagine a simple situation – you need to write an Eloquent query and order the result by the difference of two columns. Or some other calculation. Time to apply a raw query!

Simple orderBy:

```
User::where('created_at', '>', '2016-01-01')
  ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
  ->get();
```

Now, what if we need to order by the difference between **updated_at** and **created_at**? It looks like this:

```
User::where('created_at', '>', '2016-01-01')
  ->orderByRaw('(updated_at - created_at) desc')
  ->get();
```

This **orderByRaw()** method, which is not mentioned in official Laravel documentation, will apply **order by** clause without changing anything in it, so final query will be:

```
select * from users 
  where created_at > '2016-01-01' 
  order by (updated_at - created_at) desc
```

update my answer
replace this

```
->orderBy('views', 'des')->orderBy('created_at', 'des')->get()
```

to

```
 ->orderBy('views', 'desc')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks but I understand the orderByRaw() function. The only thing that's not working is the chaining of the orderByRaw & orderBy. So first order by the order of the id's and then order by the views.

Comment: Or if you know this. Just I would like to show how it is working and it will be usefull for somebody in future. I updated my answer!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.  Each `orderByRaw` and `orderBy` clause returns the query builder, so you can chain off of them.  If you output `->toSql()` at the end, you can see the generated output.

Comment: This answer would fit more as a comment under the question. What do you think?

Comment: This is the SQL I get when I do toSql(). Why isn't this working?
SELECT * 
FROM   `products` 
WHERE  `id` IN ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
ORDER  BY Field(id, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), 
          `views` DESC, 
          `created_at` DESC

Comment: It shows that the raw Query is working, but you have a typo in your original query.  `des` should be `desc`.  Build out your table in http://sqlfiddle.com/ and we can better see it.